# Drawing scaled emoji icons on iOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, emoji

I'm trying to implement my own emoji icon keyboard and have some problems. I'm trying to draw emoji icons at the same size as on native iOS emoji keyboard, but when doing simple drawing (standard unicode characters like `"\ue415"`) icons always appear at original size. When trying to increase the font - emoji icons stay of the same size. When applying CGAffineTransform for scaling - drawn icons are  bigger, but pixelated and blurred. How should I go about drawing emoji icons bigger, but sharper?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emojis won't scale beyond 16px font-size on IOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702013/emojis-wont-scale-beyond-16px-font-size-on-ios-7)

Comment: @mahaltertin please check the questions' dates.

Comment: i see, and the other question has a working answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The emoji icons are stored as PNG files in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework (I found this info on the net, but I can't confirm since I don't own a jailbroken iPhone). I don't think it is possible to scale them without loosing quality.

Comment: Any idea where they reside in iOS5? I can't find them at that location on my iPhone (5.0.1)

Answer (score 6):

ei, You can set the font to scaled the emoji icon like this:

```
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleColorEmoji" size:16.0];
```

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 5, the png files are gone because they have moved to the same font used in OSX Lion. It's called Apple Color Emoji.