# ios safari emoji font size error (can not scale up)

Tags: html, ios, safari, emoji

I'm try to using some ios emoji in my html like this:

```
<h1></h1>
```

and when I change the font size like:

```
<h1 style="font-size: 100px;"></h1>
```

the emoji scales up in safari (mac) correctly but dose not scales at all in safari (ios) -- it seems like the font size has no effect on emoji in safari (ios).

I'm not sure if it is the truth ...

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: could you please refer this below link

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702013/emojis-wont-scale-beyond-16px-font-size-on-ios-7

Answer (score 0):

Try using a pseudo-element.

```css
.custard::after {
      content: "\1F36E";
      font-size: 100px;
}
```

See pen: http://codepen.io/tibi/pen/EKQVWM